# Native Angular 10+ Dynamic Breadcrumb

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

I have been searching for few days for Angular 10+ dynamic breadcrumb with lazy loading and found nothing that is really worth entertaining. I have found old plugins that are no longer supported or plugins that don't work with angular 10+. I find this to be extremely odd....

I am looking for a native implementation for Angular 10+ dynamic breadcrumb with lazy loading; I truly appreciate your input here. Here is my attempt that I am not able to get it to work...

```
Layout.component.ts 
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../features/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'SomeModel',
        loadChildren: () => import('../features/somemodel/somemodel.module').then(m => m.SomeModel)
      }
    ]
  },
  }
];
```

SomeModel Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'somemodel',
    component: CreateUserComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'create-user',
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'list-user',
    component: ListUserComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: 'list-user',
    },
  },
];
```

BreadCrumb component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {distinctUntilChanged, filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {BreadCrumb} from './breadcrumb';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.scss']
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  breadcrumbs = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(event => this.buildBreadCrumb(this.activatedRoute.root))
  );

  // Build your breadcrumb starting with the root route of your current activated route

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  buildBreadCrumb(route: ActivatedRoute, url: string = '',
                  breadcrumbs: Array<BreadCrumb> = []): Array<BreadCrumb> {
    // If no routeConfig is avalailable we are on the root path
    const label: any = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.data.breadcrumb : 'Home';
    const path = route.routeConfig ? route.routeConfig.path : '';
    // In the routeConfig the complete path is not available,
    // so we rebuild it each time
    const nextUrl = `${url}${path}/`;
    const breadcrumb = {
      label,
      url: nextUrl,
    };
    const newBreadcrumbs = [...breadcrumbs, breadcrumb];
    if (route.firstChild) {
      // If we are not on our current path yet,
      // there will be more children to look after, to build our breadcumb
      return this.buildBreadCrumb(route.firstChild, nextUrl, newBreadcrumbs);
    }
    return newBreadcrumbs;
  }
}
```

breadcrumb.ts

```
export interface BreadCrumb {
  label: string;
  url: string;
}
```

layout.component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
              <!--<li class="breadcrumb-item" *ngFor="let breadCrumb of breadCrumbs">
                <ng-container *ngIf="breadCrumb.url">
                  <a [routerLink]="breadCrumb.url">{{breadCrumb.name}}</a>
                </ng-container>
                <span *ngIf="!breadCrumb.url">{{breadCrumb.name}}</span>
              </li>

              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard v1</li>-->
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
```

but nothing is getting displayed....
any help or direction is truly appreciate it. I am only looking for a native Angular breadcrumb implementation.

Comment: Have a look at this answer I wrote on generating dynamic breadcrumb https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969705/13680115

Comment: npm package that should help with basic dynamic breadcrumbs [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb) [ng-dynamic-breadcrumb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb)

Comment: I am looking for a native way using angular itself....

Comment: @Owen, will this work with lazy loading. for example, if I have a core module that has a routing that load the component routing using loadChildren: () => import('../somemodule').then(m => m.someModule). do you think you update your answer for lazy loading?

Comment: No update is needed, it works for both lazy loading and normal routes

Comment: Hi @OwenKelvin am also looking for the same.  after installing `ng-dynamic-breadcrumb@6.0.0` am getting below error 

`Error: ./node_modules/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb/fesm2015/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb.js 122:10-28
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'`

Btwn am using angular 11x. Could you pls create stackblitz ?